# Social Security and 401(k) withdrawal tax implications

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I am 67 and will be living on SS and 401(k) withdrawals.

```
SS for my wife and me   $49,000
Planned 401(k) annually $35,000
No other income planned
-------------------------------
Total                   $84,000
```

What portion of this money is taxable?

Comment: Traditional (i.e. not Roth) 401k?

Answer (score 1):

All of your 401k income is taxable and no more than 85% of your SS income. You can use the worksheets in [IRS: Publication 915](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p915.pdf) to determine what percentage of your SS is taxable.

Just as with ordinary income, deductions/exemptions apply and not all that is taxable will be taxed.

When you begin drawing SS you'll have the option to have taxes withheld at various rates, more convenient than quarterly estimated payments in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

$19,175 is taxable. 
If you didn't start taking the SS benefit, you might wish to consider drawing down more on the 401(k) while you let the SS benefit grow 8% each year until age 70.
You can also move some 401(k) money to an IRA and convert it to a Roth IRA account. This would help future withdrawals lessen or negate the tax of your SS benefits.